# Error in Join SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying search using following join query

```
SELECT comm_date,
      bus_prof,
      phone,
      state,
      display_name
FROM spt_identity
WHERE display_name IN ( SELECT regexp_substr(name,'[^:]+$') AS display_name
                        FROM spt_task_result
                        WHERE name LIKE 'Join%'
                          AND completion_status = 'Error'
                      );
```

it is not showing expected result .
But if I try using

```
SELECT comm_date,
      bus_prof,
      phone,
      state,
      display_name
FROM spt_identity
WHERE display_name IN ('dc99', 'hf99');
```

It gives the actual result.

Comment: please post data from spt_identity and spt_task_result

Comment: The answer is that your subquery isn't returning anything which matches in the `WHERE` clause.  Sample data would really help here.

Comment: Check to make sure NAME is actually a column in SPT_TASK_RESULT because if not, the query will *still* work - it will just reference the outer NAME.  And always alias your columns to avoid this error (if this is indeed the case)

Comment: What do you expect from the regular expression you use?

Comment: why do you think that both should show the same result?

Comment: Run the sub-query standalone. Does it return what you expect?

Comment: @jarlh yes the subqueries stand alone runs successfully